# Caching values in Python list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm using the following list comprehension:

```
resources = [obj.get("file") for obj in iterator if obj.get("file") != None]
```

Is there a way to "cache" the value of `obj.get("file")` when it's checked in the if statement so that it doesn't have to call `get` again on obj when it generates the return list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to stay with list / iterator comprehensions instead of using `filter` you can simply use:

```
resources = [file_obj
             for file_obj in (obj.get("file") for obj in iterator)
             if file_obj is not None]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
resources = filter(None, (obj.get("file") for obj in iterator))
```

See the documentation for [filter](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) for how to provide your own evaluation function. Passing `None` for the function (as above) filters out all values which aren't true.

If obj.get() returns an object which has a weird `__nonzero__` method then you'd need to pass `lambda obj: obj != None` to get exactly the same result as your original code.

Comment: "an object which has a weird __nonzero__" - like an int, or a str.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
resources = filter( lambda x: x is not None, [obj.get("file") for ob jin iterator])
```

Comment: You don't need the lambda function in your filter.  By passing None it defaults to the identity function (so any object that evaluates to false will be filtered out).  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: On second thought, you might want the lambda if you have other "False" elements in your iterable (i.e. 0).

Comment: Hmm.  even if i don't need it, I like the explicitness of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary dict to hold values. Then, create a function that uses this dict as a cache, and use that function in the list comprehension, like so:

```
obj_cache = {}

def cache_get (target, key):
    if (target, key) not in obj_cache: obj_cache[(target, key)] = target.get(key)
    return obj_cache[(target, key)]

resources = [cache_get(obj, "file") for obj in iterator if cache_get(obj, "file") != None]
```

Also, you probably already know this (and if so, please disregard this answer), but unless obj.get("file") is making a database call, opening a file, making a request over a network, or doing something else potentially expensive, calling it twice per iteration instead of once is probably harmless, since you're only adding O(n) to your cost.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Python 3.8 one can use an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to avoid calling the function twice:

```
iterator = [{'file': 'abc'}, 
            {'file': None}, 
            {'file': 'def'}, 
            {'file': None}]
res = [file for obj in iterator 
       if (file := obj.get("file")) is not None]
print(res)
# ['abc', 'def']
```