# Optimization on Python list comprehension

Tags: python

```
[getattr(x, contact_field_map[communication_type])
                            for x in curr_role_group.contacts if
                            getattr(x, contact_field_map[communication_type])]
```

The above is my list comprehension. The initial function and the filter clause call getattr twice. Will Python run this twice or does it optimize the calculation internally knowing it can cache the result after the first call?

If Python doesn't do the optimization, how can I rewrite it to run faster?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, Python never tries to be clever - there's a good chance someone tries to be clever'er and breaks assumptions. For example, `getattr` may call an overwritten `__getattr__` that has side-effects. As *another* rule of thumb, Python's builtins are fast, and doing micro-optimizations isn't worth it. Unless you have profiled your code and see a bottleneck here, don't bother.

Comment: Or more commonly than calling `__getattr__`, calling a `@property`

Comment: I hadn't considered that getattr might have side effects.

Comment: Related: [Caching values in Python list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/971857/7851470).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python will run the `getattr` twice -- It doesn't do any optimization (after all, how does it know that the first attribute fetch doesn't change the value of the second one?)

To optimize the query, you can do it in 2 stages.  The first stage computes the values using a generator expression, the second stage filters those values:

```
gen = (getattr(x, contact_field_map[communication_type])
                        for x in curr_role_group.contacts)
result = [item for item in gen if item]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
[res for x in curr_role_group.contacts 
     for res in [getattr(x, contact_field_map[communication_type])] if res]
```

For example, instead of

```
[i**2 for i in range(10) if i**2 < 10]
Out: [0, 1, 4, 9]
```

You can do

```
[res for i in range(10) for res in [i**2] if res < 10]
Out: [0, 1, 4, 9]
```

Here, you are computing `i**2` only once.

Comment: Creating a list (even with just one element) should be rather costly compared to simple operations. Did you time it? Is there a notable difference to using a generator instead of a list?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You are right, this is probably an overkill for getattr. It would make sense if you have a costly function and you want to reduce the number of calls to that function. For `i**2`, both answers are slower than the original. For an operation that takes some time, generators are slightly faster. http://imgur.com/HDxpMcR

Comment: Great, thanks for testing and timing! It seems like the `list` overhead really is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a generator for the entire thing? Something like:

```
def gen():
   for x in curr_role_group.contacts:
       value = getattr(x, contact_field_map[communication_type])
       if value:
           yield value

result = list(gen())
```

Comment: The entire set can be condensed to a generator expression. See @mgilson's solution