# Evaluation of function in python list comprehension action step and condition at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-comprehension

I am interested in what does python under the hood in the following code.

```py
def test_func(a: str) -> str or None:
    # Just example
    if a.endswith("r"):
        return f"{a}rr"
    elif a.endswith("s"):
        return None
    else:
        return a

if __name__=="__main__":
    ...
    source_list = ["Edgar", "Pedros", "Alexander"]
    test = [test_func(x) for x in source_list if test_func(x)]
```

My question here is how python under the hood copes with the evaluation of the `test_func(x)` function. Is it done twice or python is able to recognize that the same result can be used on both places and evaluates the function only once? :-)

Comment: what happens if you put a print in `test_func` and run it on a single element? Does it print once or twice?

Comment: That is exactly what I have done when I have posted the question. :-)

Comment: My goal, rather than answer your question, was to show you how you could answer the question yourself, which you did! If you've answered your question, then you should accept your answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Optimization on Python list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627620/optimization-on-python-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah, so I just add there a print statement to the function and it has revealed itself.

The answer is that in case the condition is evaluated as positive the function is evaluated twice. Here is my example:

```
>>> def test(a: str) -> str or None:
...     print(f"HERE {a}")
...     if a.endswith("r"):
...         return f"{a}rr"
...     elif a.endswith("s"):
...         return None
...     else:
...         return a
...
>>> source = ["Edgar", "Pedros", "Alexander"]
>>> [test(x) for x in source if test(x)]
HERE Edgar
HERE Edgar
HERE Pedros
HERE Alexander
HERE Alexander
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.8+, you can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) which is perfect for this!

```
test = [tested for x in source_list if (tested := test_func(x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

It calls `test_func(x)` twice for elements for which its truth value is true (and once for those whose truth value is false).  If you only want to call it once in all cases, you can do:

```
test = [v for v in (test_func(x) for x in source_list) if v]
```

Comment: Thank you @TomKarzes I have just realized how to test it after I have posted the question, but anyway it can be helpful to the others, because I haven't found that question here when I was checking it in advance. :-)

Comment: @VaPo The main point is to write your code so that it only calls it once (if the function is expensive).  You can first create a list, then filter the list, or you can avoid creating the intermediate list by doing what I showed above, which is to create a generator and then filter the generator values directly to create the result list.

Comment: That is exactly what I was also thinking about to filter the list in a separate step. :-) Thank you for the hint. :-)

Answer (score 0):

unless you store function results, as soon as you write a function name with pair of parenthesis new call to the function occur

Comment: Regarding the storing of the results, I would have another question. What will be faster - having C-like for loop with storing of the value or python comprehension with two evaluations? I know that this can be a tricky question because it might depend on the calculations in the function, but lets say that the function will be that easy string manipulation as proposed in the example above. What I am pointing to is, that I have heard that python comprehension is faster than C-like for cycles used in python, but I do not know how much faster.